# Find an infinity of differentiable solutions to $y'=y^{1/3}, y(0)=0$

Tags: real-analysis

> Find an infinity of differentiable solutions to$$y'=y^{1/3}, y(0)=0,$$
>   valid on the whole $x$-axis.

I  can find $y=(\frac{2}{3}x)^{3/2}$ or $y=0$, but I can't find a third.

Comment: When you integrate, how about a constant?

Comment: Define $y(x)=0$ for every $x\leqslant x_0$ and $y(x)=\left(\frac23(x-x_0)\right)^{3/2}$ for every $x\geqslant x_0$, for any nonnegative $x_0$.